# Angular <mat-select> dropdown is not working along with nebular theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement  (angular material UI) along with the nebular components
but  is not working when same component/module has nebular imports . if i remove imports of nebular module mat-select works .

with using nebular version 4.1.1 and version of angular material 8.2.3

Here is my stackblitz workaround that you can clearly see that select dropdown is not working.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ngmzqm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html

Comment: Same, i am trying to use mat-table inside nebular components? is it possible to use mat-table with nebular?

Answer (score 0):

**Just make sure you have this in your app.component.html.**

```
<nb-layout>
    <nb-layout-column>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another forum that discuss about this.. you can check it out [here](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/1663)..
They speak about using the nb theme only to one component and avoid it being clashing with the material ui in the other components